# Menu from Activity is not overflowing Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

The Issue: I've created Activity that contains Drawer and FrameLayout that will be inflated by fragments.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment_panel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@id/drawerPanel"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/backgroundColor">

        <-- CONTENT->>
    </RelativeLayout>





    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

After changing/inflating the fragment into FrameLayout *main_fragment_panel* the drawer should open (everything in logs looks fine) but looks like the fragment overflows everything from activity. How can I change the "level" or "priority" of layout?
**UPDATE:** I've updated code above - its displaying properly now but didn't handle any events from <-- CONTENT --> (there are some buttons there with listeners)

Comment: put FrameLayout inside the DrawerLayout tag

Comment: thank you @tahsinRupam. Please post it separate so I could mark as answer ;) btw. now the items within the menu are not clickable :(

Comment: I have edited my answer. Let me know if this works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use DrawerLayout as parent layout. Here is the revised code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

     <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        android:background="@color/background_material_dark"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: that works perfectly but no event in menu is handled  :( after clicking on some menu item it just closes the drawer

Comment: I have to leave my office now. I will give the modified answer when I will reach home. Stay with me :p

Comment: its working now! I did some weird thing on my side! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
        android:name="com.fragments.RightFragment"//your left fragment
        android:layout_width="@dimen/drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

your drawer layout should look like this;

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- The main content view -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <!-- Menu items--->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:background="@drawable/background_drawer"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Now for replacing fragments use:

```
FragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, tag);
```

Comment: as much as I love idea of NavigationView I have really uncommon menu when it comes to design and I would like to stay away from NavigationView. 
I've updated the original question - right now its opening properly but there is no events for it :(